# Knockout.js applyBindings and getJson doesnt show?

Tags: knockout.js

Im new to knockout and im trying to display a table which contains data from mt DB. 
In my controller, (DriversController), I have this code:

```
 public JsonResult GetAllDrivers()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Driver> drivers = db.Drivers.ToList();
        return Json(drivers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my index HTML (CSHTML):

```
 <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Driver Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: drivers">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text: DriverId"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
```

the fields in the "text:" are exactly like they are in the DB table.

My viewModel:

```
<script>
                        var drivers

                        $.getJSON("/Drivers/GetAllDrivers", function (data) {
                            drivers = data
                            ko.applyBindings(drivers)
                        })
                    </script>
```

Id followed a lot of tutorials and did exactly what they did but somehow nothing is working :( i get a blank page which only cointains the table headers.
help? thanks

Comment: Any errors in the console of the browser? log the data maybe it is empty...console.info(data)

Comment: `foreach: drivers` implies that your model contains a property named `drivers` (that is also an array), but that is not the case since your root viewmodel itself *is* the array of drivers. Either change to `foreach: $root` or change your model to have the drivers array in a `drivers` property: `ko.applyBindings({drivers: drivers})`

Answer (score 1):

your data must look like

```
{drivers:[{DriverId:1,firstName:'test'}]}
```

so change your code to:

```
ko.applyBindings({drivers:data})
```